# Python visualization / plotting for hh:mm values (Solar Data)

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I want to create a ridge graph with 12 subgraphs (one month each) and the solar energy produced at certain times during the day. The times are given as hh:mm values. I have a table with one column for the month, one for the time of day, and one for the average value across days.

Anything I found so far is excessively complicated, be it Joypy or SNS or Plotly. This seems like such a common problem, that I think I am missing some obvious solution or just the right search terms. Can anyone help? Thank you!

I did a simple visualization as heatmap to explain that underlying problem.

[image]